How to Calculate Z-Scores for a List of Values in Polars DataFrame
I'm working with a Polars DataFrame in Python, where I have a column containing lists of values. I need to calculate the Z-scores for each list using pre-computed mean and standard deviation values. Here’s a sample of my DataFrame:
import polars as pl

data = {
    "transcript_id": ["ENST00000711184.1"],
    "OE": [[3.933402, 1.057907, None, 3.116513]],
    "mean_OE": [11.882091],
    "std_OE": [3.889974],
}

df_human = pl.DataFrame(data)

For each list in the OE column, I want to subtract the mean (mean_OE) and divide by the standard deviation (std_OE) to obtain the Z-scores. I also want to handle None values in the lists by leaving them as None in the Z-scores list.
How can I correctly apply the Z-score calculation to each list while keeping None values intact?
Thanks in advance for any guidance!

mean_OE does not contain the mean of the list elements. Should the columns mean_OE / std_OE be used for the z-score calculation or should the usual definition be applied?

Since the last couple releases, and especially since Polars release 1.10.0, arithmetic between list columns and non-list columns simplified a lot.
If you are interested in the usual definition of the Z-score (using the summary statistics of the actual list data), the following can be used.
df_human.select(
    (pl.col("OE") - pl.col("OE").list.mean()) / pl.col("OE").list.std()
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ OE                                  │
│ ---                                 │
│ list[f64]                           │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ [1.230795, -1.6447, null, 0.413906] │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘

If you want to compute the Z-score explicitly using the mean_OE and std_OE columns, you can now use them directly.
df_human.select((pl.col("OE") - pl.col("mean_OE")) / pl.col("std_OE"))

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ OE                                      │
│ ---                                     │
│ list[f64]                               │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ [-2.043378, -2.782585, null, -2.253377] │
└─────────────────────────────────────────┘


in your list.eval approach you forgot to divide by std.

@DeanMacGregor Good catch. I’ve edited the question.

I think this can now be written "natively" with list arithmeric/broadcasting in 1.10.0

@jqurious Good point - thanks! I'll update the question soon :)

df_human.select((pl.col("OE") - pl.col("mean_OE")) / pl.col("std_OE")) also works now on 1.10.0

updated. With current version 1.10.0 arithmetic operations between lists and scalars are supported:
df_human.select(
    res = (pl.col.OE - pl.col.mean_OE) / pl.col.std_OE
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│ res                             │
│ ---                             │
│ list[f64]                       │
╞═════════════════════════════════╡
│ [-2.043378, -2.782585, … -2.25… │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

outdated

Expr.explode() to explode lists.
Expr.implode() to combine them back after applying transformations.

(
    df_human
    .select(
        res = (
            (pl.col.OE.explode() - pl.col.mean_OE) / pl.col.std_OE
        ).implode().over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
    )
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│ res                             │
│ ---                             │
│ list[f64]                       │
╞═════════════════════════════════╡
│ [-2.043378, -2.782585, … -2.25… │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

